# Sorting isometric objects with absolute pixels

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developping objects/items on my `HTML5 Canvas` isometric game.
Each object has **layers**. Each layer has an image and its predefined x, y (top, left in px).
My sorting system looks like this:

```
this.Container.drawImage(index, ...)
```

where index is calculated like this (x & y vars here are isometric)

```
1000 + x + y
```

However, I don't have any idea how to correctly sort my **layers**. I only have their **absolute** position in pixel (top, left). I've tried to calculate isometric x & y for each layer, but layers can be not precise and so it detects the tile behind so the index is wrong.

Is there anyway to correctly sort my **absolute** layers with the others objects? (players ect...)